# org.flywaydb Unique Constraint Issue

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, flyway

I am new to the Flyway. I am using JPA with the annotation based configuration to define the DB mapping.

Below is entity class with Unique key with the attribute.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Test", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "YEAR"))
public class Test
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "YEAR")
    private Long                year;
  // setter and getter
}
```

From the maven I am using `hibernate:update` it will create the successful migration script sql file. ( test_script.sql )

Below is the generated test_script.sql : 
Generated script by `hibernate:upadate` maven command:

```
// create table command
create table Test(ID number(19,0) not null, year number(19,0) not null, primary key (ID));
// Alter table command
alter table Test drop constraint UK_12131231231;
// Alter table command
alter table Test add constraint UK_12131231231unique (year);
```

When i fire the `flyway:migrate` maven command then below message I get :

```
Error code after the flyway:migrate :

SQL State  : 72000
Error Code : 2443
Message    : ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint
Statement  : alter table Test drop constraint UK_12131231231;
```

I would be tankful if anyone had faced same issue and have the solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid auto-generated constraint name,which may differ you should name it by yourself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Test",
 uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name="UQ_TEST_YEAR", columnNames = "YEAR")
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because you didn't name primary key constraint but let Oracle create it using its own algorithm - that's why its name is UK_12131231231 (bunch of numbers).

Here's a demonstration:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, primary key (id));

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C0045805

SQL>
```

I'll now drop the table and recreate it; note that constraint name has changed:

```
SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test (id number, primary key (id));

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C0045806

SQL>
```

Therefore, hardcoding constraint name in DROP CONSTRAINT command isn't a good idea as it is changed every time.

I'd suggest you to name the constraint like this:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, constraint pk_test primary key (id));

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK_TEST

SQL> alter table test drop constraint pk_test;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Aha! That's something different! Constraint name will **always** be PK_TEST, and you can freely *hardcode* it in your script, as its name won't change and you won't get `ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint`

Comment: Thanks for the update and you quick response. I am using the Maven run configuration, the script get generated  as default by the hibernate: update command

Comment: I don't know software you use nor its capabilities. I'm just saying that the way constraint name is created you can't drop it the way you're doing it now.